# How do we evaluate the exponent of a derivative operator?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators

We have the operator
$$A = -ix \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \, ,$$
and we want to show that
$$ \left[ e^{- i \alpha A} \Psi \right](x) = \Psi(e^{-\alpha}x) \, .$$

Any thoughts of showing this relationship?

Comment: Try expanding the exponential in a Taylor series.

Comment: Thank you for answering so quickly! But I tried and I got stuck, because I am not familiar with this methodology, the change in the argument of Ψ. Can you demonstrate a brief proof of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

exp(A) is just a scaling operator, so, then, a Lagrange translation operator in improved variables, $y\equiv \ln x$,
$$
\exp A=\exp (-i \frac{\partial}{\partial y })~.
$$

Now, since $\Psi (x)=\Psi(e^y)$, and further 
$$
e^{a\partial_y} f(y)= f(y+a),
$$
directly evident from the Taylor expansion of the r.h.side at *y*, you have
$$
e^{-i\alpha A} \Psi (x) = e^{-\alpha \partial_y} \Psi (e^y)=\Psi(e^{y-\alpha})=\Psi( e^{-\alpha} x).$$ 
$$

Comment: Thank you so much! I started to understand that and I am grateful to you for this!